# Drag and drop Images outside wpf Application

Tags: wpf, image, drag-and-drop

Good afternoon,

I've invested many and many topics about drag & dropping file but I didn't find a solution to my problem. The situation is the following one:

I've got Images which are in my wpf application as Resource. What I want to do is to drag and drop them when they're displayed in my app to another outside program.

Is it only possible to do that with wpf application or should I go with another solution ?

Thanks in advance,

Gronjus

Comment: Yes it is possible.First make ur dragdata to hold the file path of the file u are dragging. Second make next project to handle drop data of a file path and get the file using the file path.

Comment: I'm pretty new in wpf application so I'm bit lost . In case to know, am I supposed to use drag enter and drag leave event or ? Some people use mouse left up and left down so I don't really know with which solution I have to go ? Just to clarify, you're talking about a next project. In  mine, I would like for example to drag and drop the picture in a browser or image editor for example, is it possible ?

Comment: start with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview)

Comment: I've read most of the informations into theses topics. Now I can retrieve my imagesource in the drop, but I can't get it as image into a web browser .. Is there some king of convert to do ?